# An image added to my enterprise wiki page is automatically added inside wrong location PublishingImages/Pages/Forms/my-sub/

Tags: 2013, development, publishing-site, picture-library, image-upload

I am working on an Enterprise wiki site collection, and when users add images to the wiki pages, these images are going to be stored inside the following folder automatically:-

```
[ServerName]/[SiteCollectionPath]/PublishingImages/Pages/[Wiki Page Name]/
```

But currently I have note that there is an image which is stored under this path

```
[ServerName]/[SiteCollectionPath]/PublishingImages/Pages/Forms/my-sub/
```

As follow:-

[image]

So what is my-sub folder? and what could cause this image specifically not to be stored under the folder that have the wiki page name ?, baring in mind that the wiki page containing this image have other images and all of these image were stored under the normal link:-

```
[ServerName]/[SiteCollectionPath]/PublishingImages/Pages/[Wiki Page Name]/
```

Can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks